# Открыть приложение в google play

Tags: мобильные-приложения, google-play, html

Добрый день!

Есть сайт + мобильное приложение.
Необходимо сделать следующие вещи:

Если на сайт зашли через мобильное устройство, определять, какой это телелфон - Андройд или АйФон, и показывать всплывающее окно - мол, скачайте мобильное приложение.
Если человек нажимает скачать, то открывается Google Play или iTunse (мобильное приложение, а не сайт).

Я видел такие фишки на сайтах, только понятия не имею, как это сделано, или есть уже готовые плагины для этого?

Буду признателен. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` и поиск (пишу с телефона, развернуто не могу).